# Upgrading Laptop Memory Question

Tags: upgrade, laptop, hardware, ram

Ok, I've had my current laptop for a while. (purchased from Zareason with Ubuntu 12.04 pre-installed, about 2008 or so.) It runs like a champ. I can't remember the model. I even called Zareason and they told me that my purchase isn't on their new system so, they can't even tell me the model.

I just bought memory to upgrade the Windows laptops in the house so, I figured I'd look into upgrading my own.

Through some investigation and picking through this site I have discovered that I have a total of 4 slots that can be maxxed out at 32Gb (4x8Gb). Currently, only 2-4Gb chips are installed. (SODIMM DDR3 1600mhz.)

My question is, is there any other info that would be useful so I can have the best chance at buying the right memory to max out my laptop at 32GB?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is not related to Ubuntu and is off-topic here.

Comment: Weird, because I bought it custom built with ubuntu 12.04 pre-installed

Comment: OS doesn't matter at all in this case. It is a 100% hardware question.

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about hardware recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most memory manufacturers have a compatibility list of what hardware their modules have been tested with. For example, go to [Crucial](http://crucial.com), put in the make and model of the laptop, and it'll show you the list of compatible module part numbers. You can then either buy some on the spot, or look for the part number elsewhere.

Based on your dmidecode output, it looks like what you have is a MSI MS-16GD. If that is the case (google some pictures of it to verify), [these should be the compatible modules from Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/msi(microstar)/ms-16gd).

Comment: Thanks for your clear and concise answer but as stated, I can not find the make/model since it was custom built and I no longer have the paperwork. I only know what memory is currently installed.

Comment: Most "custom" laptops are rebadged Clevos. What do you get from `dmidecode`?

Comment: Results of dmicode https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/g5frSGVHkv/

Comment: Answer above updated based on the dmidecode information.

Comment: I'd like to take a moment to thank you for taking the time to help and answer my question to its fullest extent. If more users on here took the time and care that you did, everyone would be better off. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem, any time. :-)